# Plone: catalog_object method won't add my (AT) objects

Tags: plone, archetypes, plone-4.x

I have a transmogrifier pipeline to insert objects to my Zope database (importing zexp files from a directory structure).  This works - the objects are created; but I don't get them added to the portal_catalog.

I added a section to add the objects to the catalog explicitly, inspired by `plone.app.transmogrifier.reindexobject`: I call `portal_catalog.catalog_object(obj)` for each item.

The objects exist, and `getPhysicalPath` yields the correct values, but the objects are not added.  There is no error message or exception whatsoever.

I tried to specify the list of indexes (the `idxs` argument), but this didn't change anything.  If not specified, all indexes should be filled anyway, right?

Since it looks like a `transaction` problem to me (no errors, but nothing stored in the catalog either), I tried transaction code (begin, savepoint, commit, and in case of exceptions abort), but it didn't help. When I call the catalog immediately after the `catalog_object` call (`portal_catalog(path='/Plonesite/full/path/to/object')`), nothing has happened, and an empty list is returned.

The catalog does contain objects; even objects of my custom datatypes (AT-based).  Not even the `Folder` objects of my imports are indexed.

Without the objects in the catalog, my import is useless.  What can I do?

Thank you!

**Edit**: Any hint about how to get my object trees in the catalog is appreciated!  Even if it can't be integrated in my process.  I need the contents cataloged ...

My custom content types *are* contained in the `Plone Catalog Tool` page selection field, but I don't know whether this is sufficient.

**Edit 2:**
Somehow my objects *have* been catalogued - [the `unrestrictedSearchResults` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153667/1051649) shows them!  However, it can't be the desired solution to use this method all over; so I need to "un-restrict" the entries somehow.

Comment: Not a resolution for your original question, but you can still go to ZMI and click the "Clean and rebuild" button in the catalog tool.
It will index all of your objects.

Comment: +1 to what keul said.  My memory is hazy on this, but I seem to remember that plone.app.transmogrifier.reindexobject didn't work for me as I expected. I usually had to rebuild the catalog manually after a transmogrifier run.  I too am interested to know if there's another way.

Comment: I'm aware of the `Clean and rebuild` action; sadly, it doesn't help (yet). Probably there is still a problem with my objects, but the field I suspected to be the cause didn't do the trick ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have a `monkey:patch` (`xmlns:monkey="http://namespaces.plone.org/monkey"`) for the `Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool.CatalogTool.searchResults` method; this filters the catalog for my additional field `subportal` unless a special value for it is given - even in the management view ... Unfortunately, I had no way to specify this special value in that view.

Thus, the solution was to weed out all wrong values (for `subportal`s which don't exist in the other Zope tree) to have the default value take effect.

Quite specific to my setup, I'm afraid ...